# rails_admin gem only allow edit action for certain model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, action, rails-admin

i'm using rails_admin gem. In admin page I have a model called Staff. 
Is possible only allow edit action for this model? I want to disable new,destroy ect ect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CanCan to configure the authorization in Rails Admin. [This wiki](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/CanCan#railsadmin-verbs) tells you how to setup possible verbs for each model.

You could also hack the views to set `visibility:hidden` etc, but I would prefer the CanCan way.

Comment: I prefer the second solution, can you provide more details to implement it ?